# Where are buffers located?

Tags: process, operating-system, kernel, buffer

I hear a lot about *flushing buffers*, *sending to buffer* etc. but I don't have a visual image about where buffers reside and how they look like.

Are buffers part of the OS' kernel or part of each process? If the case is the first, can the same buffers be used by multiple processes?

Comment: A buffer is a generic term in programming---it's something that can hold a stream of data, usually for a temporary purpose. Is it specifically I/O buffers that you are interested in understanding?

Comment: @Jaywalker yes. Or are there other kinds of buffers..?

Answer (score 2):

A buffer is a generic term for a collection of bytes, typically used in the context of either sending, receiving or storing information where the internal data-structure of the information isn't important.

In the case of "flushing" buffers, this typically is used in the context of sending data either to a file or network; the buffer in this case being used to coalesce multiple small writes to the file or network into one larger and more-efficient-to-transmit buffer. After the final write has been performed (or after some "commit" point), the buffer must be "flushed" to ensure that any data left waiting to coalesce with a future write is committed immediately to the underlying file sent over the network rather than left waiting for a future write that might never come.

In both the case of network and file IO, buffers are usuaully used in multiple places. File IO may well be buffered by a buffer in the application, in a library (for instance an implementation of fwrite may buffer the output), in the kernel and even on the device itself - network writes may well be buffered by the device whilst waiting for bandwidth on the wire and hard-disk drives will buffer output from the OS to ensure that data isn't lost as the physical platters spin to the correct position for the write.

Comment: Nice answer in general. In the context of programming software, a buffer "usually" refers to the one maintained by the OS (or underlying runtime, if there is one).